# Left Join / Not In returning diff results

Tags: sql-server

This is my data structure and I am wanting to return all results from #1 that do not exist in #ValuesDenied.  My 1st query errors due to it not knowing what #ValuesDenied.[sin] is referencing.  My 2nd query knows what the previous is referencing but returns all results even though 2 of them should be excluded by my left join?

```
Create Table #1
(
  ID int,
  rsl varchar(100),
  [sin] varchar(100),
  teamname varchar(100) 
)

Create Table #ValuesDenied
(
  ID int,
  originalID int,
  rsl varchar(100),
  [sin] varchar(100),
  teamname varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #1 Values (1, 'MKX', 'Approved', 'Alpha'), (2, 'MKZ', 'Approved', 'Omega'), (3, 'RMN', 'Approved', 'Delta')
INSERT INTO #ValuesDenied VALUES (200, 1, 'MKX', 'Manager Denied', 'Alpha'), (400, 2, 'MKZ', 'Supervisor Returned', 'Omega')

Select #1.ID, #1.[sin], #1.teamname, #ValuesDenied.[sin]
FROM #1
WHERE #1.ID NOT IN (Select originalID FROM #ValuesDenied)
AND #1.[sin] = 'Approved'

Select #1.ID, #1.[sin], #1.teamname, #ValuesDenied.[sin]
FROM #1
LEFT JOIN #ValuesDenied
ON #1.ID = #ValuesDenied.originalID
WHERE #1.[sin] = 'Approved'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st query errors out because you're referencing an unknown column `#ValuesDenied.[sin]`. You're selecting from the `#1` table and not `#ValueDenied`. You should remove it.

```
Select #1.ID, #1.[sin], #1.teamname
FROM #1
WHERE 
    #1.ID NOT IN (Select originalID FROM #ValuesDenied)
    AND #1.[sin] = 'Approved'
```

The 2nd query is returning all rows because you're not filtering them. You should add `#ValuesDenied.originalID IS NULL` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    #1.*
FROM #1
LEFT JOIN #ValuesDenied
    ON #1.ID = #ValuesDenied.originalID
WHERE
    #1.sin = 'Approved'
    AND #ValuesDenied.originalID IS NULL
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          rsl     sin        teamname
----------- ------- ---------- -----------
3           RMN     Approved   Delta
```